# How to seal a heater flue joint on the roof?

Tags: roof, crack, exhaust-vent

I noticed a crack in the joint between my heater vent and the roof.  The crack is wide enough (see pic) such that the wood attic flooring beneath the cavity has warped from the rain.  I think who ever worked on the job should have lowered the skirt further down so that the opening is covered.

I can't move the skirt down, and even if I can snip it off, I can't seem to take off the head of the vent in order to slide down another skirt.  I think I need to apply some type of silicone.

- What's the best way to close the crack?
- Is there a brand of silicon (preferably from Home Depot) that is heat resistant (since it is coming from my heater) and UV resistant (so that it won't crack from the sun) and water resistant?
- What type of paint is used to match the color afterwards?
- Is it sprayed on or painted on?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, caulk the opening where the water is getting in.

Then remove the ring that is too high and doing nothing.

I have had great success with covering the old boot with a [new boot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Perma-Boot-Pipe-Boot-for-3-in-I-D-Vent-Pipe-Black-Color-New-Construction-Reroof-PB-312-3BK/203218184?g_store=&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D22-022_010_ROOFING-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-4035567-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-Pmax-CL3TestA&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D22-022_010_ROOFING-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-4035567-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-Pmax-CL3TestA-71700000103694446--&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1OmoBhDXARIsAAAYGSFm3av4_JwTzKXxstKNw6uSpuAeSoASHEcQCV3Lu7PVO23lcJA9l-saArLmEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

( Product recommendation is discouraged, but these "reboot" products have saved a lot of time and worked well. )

If you need to paint, a good exterior paint will work. Sprayed or brushed doesn't matter. It is up on the roof, so a slight color variation will not matter.

Comment: What type of caulk?  It probably needs to be heat and uv resistant.  Have any brand in mind that you can recommend?

I am not sure the existing storm collar is moveable.  Tried to move it but it wont budge

Comment: A polyurethane caulk should work well.  It can't be that hot or your shingles would start to get very sticky.  That collar will come off, you may have to cut it.  The new boot will cover the vent pipe and the crack, so UV will not be an issue.

Comment: Don't _remove_ the ring. Move it down on top of the caulk (before it's cured) and add more caulk over it.